# Getting XML parsing error when creating HTML document via concordion excel extension

Tags: xml-parsing, concordion

[Fatal Error] :1:326: Attribute name "https:" associated with an element type "span" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
Error parsing generated HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?><html xmlns:concordion="http://www.concordion.org/2007/concordion"><head><title>XMLSuccess.xlsx</title></head><body><h1>XMLSuccess.xlsx</h1><div excel-location="Sheet1" class="example"><h2>Sheet1</h2><p><span excel-location="B1" concordion:set="#flatRate" style="font-size: 11pt; " https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid="70924">1</span></p><p><span excel-location="B2" concordion:set="#cpm1" style="font-size: 11pt; " https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid="70924">0.9</span></p></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at your source Excel file to see where the `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid="70924"`could be coming from? If you are unable to fix or believe it's an issue with the extension, please raise an issue at https://github.com/concordion/concordion-excel-extension/issues including a reproducible test case.